# How to retrieve lost worksheets in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(submitting on behalf of a client)

.........................

User(xyz) has lost all the worksheets after executing "`Create or Replace User xyz`". Is there a way to get all the lost worksheets back for the user ?

The user is essentially being dropped and recreated (just the login name changed, username is the same for this user). I don't think there's any method at this time to restore a user that's been "dropped", and the worksheets would be in the stage specifically associated with that user.

.........................

Any recommendations from other users who've run into this issue? THX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, once the user is dropped, the worksheets can not be retrieved.

However, as a workaround, The Accounts_Usage view can be used to retrieve queries
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html

This looks like the only way to retrieve old queries after a user has been dropped or deleted.

Comment: use role accountadmin ; 
select * from snowflake.account_usage.query_history where username = 'XXX' ; 

It should have last 1 year of data. I recommend storing it once or twice per year.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be possible once they are disconnected from the user. It is worth a support ticket to see if somebody has some tricks up their sleeve there.

Answer (score 0):

The client is correct. There is currently no capability in Snowflake to restore a user that has been dropped/replaced and the worksheets would be in the stage specifically associated with that user.

Comment: FYI, this will change with Snowsight.